# Removing ^M from output when appending to file via nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my nodejs script, I have output from the console that I append to a file. Here's the pseudo-code:

```
var append_fn = function (out) {
    fs.appendFile('file.txt', out, 'utf8');
};
var spawn_res = spawn('command', ['-args']);
spawn_res.stdout.on('data', append_fn);
```

The problem I'm having is that when I open the text file using *nano* [text editor], I see `^M` scattered around. I understand this is the carriage-return character.

Is there a way I can eliminate these characters and just have a new-line instead i.e. the way I would see the output on a normal command line?

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace carriage returns before you write the string to the file:

```
out = out.toString();
out = out.split("\r\n").join("\n");
```

**EDIT:** Test code

Try this code:

```
out = out.toString();
console.log("BEFORE: " + out.split("\r\n").length);
out = out.split("\r\n").join("\n");
console.log("AFTER: " + out.split("\r\n").length);
```

If you get `BEFORE: 1` you don't need to replace and the problem is elsewhere.

If you get `BEFORE: x` (with `x > 1`) and get `AFTER: 1` you need to replace but there's another problem further down.

Comment: Tried this but it didn't work. First, it gave me `split is not a function`. Then when I did `out.toString.split`, the error went away, but I still see the `^M`.

Comment: I've added a test, let's see what you get.